# Is there a general term for a mapping of a set to itself?

Tags: terminology

I often wish to describe a mapping of a set to itself as *injective*, or *bijective*, etc.  The sentence *$f$ is an injective mapping of the set $\mathcal{A}$ into itself* seems unnecessarily wordy.  I would like to say something like: *$f$ is an injective endomapping of the set $\mathcal{A}.$*  Where I have coined the term *endomapping* to mean the mapping of a set to itself.

Is there an established mathematical term for this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your first version:  everyone would understand it.  One could argue your second version is unnecessarily high-falutin'.

Comment: [self-map](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Self-Map.html) is sometimes used.

Comment: it's called a self-map

Comment: @user29418 that would make Fowler and Fowler happy.  "Prefer the Saxon word."

Comment: "Endomap" and "endofunction" work but are IMO slightly awkward. I don't really know a non-awkward term.